# How to close a ftp connection in unix shell script

Tags: unix, ftp

I want to close a FTP connection while the connection is inactive, for some reason, not always while a file is transferred it get stuck, then as I'm using Unix Shell script, the connection remain opened without transfer anything and it can't continue with the next line because is stuck with the ftp command line

there is a way to end an inactive connection from unix shell script?

```
ftp -nv <<-EOD > ${tmpftplog}
open ${server}
user ${username} ${password}
put ${datafile} ${mfDatafile} //<---Line Stuck!!
bye
EOD
```

This is what I have, put command is stuck (not always) but I want to close the ftp if there is no connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: You said the problem is that ftp is stuck when the connection *remains open*, and you also said that you want to close it when there is *no connection*. Which connection state do you want to test for?

Comment: No, I mean, the FTP connection while is transferring a file, sometimes, not always the file is stuck and the connection remain open, can pass 3 hours and is stuck in that line with the connection open and without transferring anything and then the ksh shell script can't continue with the script.

Comment: What operating system are you running `ftp` on?

Comment: it's SunOS, that's the operating system.

Comment: If you have Solaris 11, you might want to try the `timeout` command, which will run another command (such as ftp) and will terminate it if it runs for longer than a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh

FTP_USERNAME=username
FTP_PASSWORD=password
FTP_SERVER=ftp_address

run_access_server()
{
              lftp <<STOP
              open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_SERVER
              # put your commands here
              bye
STOP
}

run_access_server
```

Let me know if u need anything else.